# missing class label in multi-class segmentation

Tags: pytorch, image-segmentation, multiclass-classification

I am performing segmentation of 8 tissue classes. After certain epochs, 7 tissue classes have more or less expected results. But out of eight class 1 is always not being predicted at all. For example, look at the image below:

[image]

This is the network output I am plotting from the validation set. In almost all the samples, the eyeball label is missing and has 0 (background) voxels. But in train input images eyeball intensities are in the range of 20-30 and the background is ~0.

I am using PyTorch and thinking about gradient accumulation to ensure the network sees all the different tissue classes before backpropagation.

Edit:

@Ivan Here is the voxel count of the data per class in the X-axis. I ignored the background voxels(which is 0). Also, the eyeballs class is 7. Not sure what other statistics you wanted. Let me know.
class 7 and 8 have almost the same number of voxels but training misses class 7 completely.

[image]

Comment: What are your classes statistics in the dataset you use?

Comment: @Ivan I added a plot of the voxel/pixel count per class as an answer. Please take a look.

Comment: What class corresponds to eyeballs?

Comment: @Ivan please check the plot [here](https://imgur.com/ghdP1Mn). The eyeballs are labelled as class 7. Though while cropping patches I took more samples from eyeball region but total number of voxels of eyeballs and also class 8 are dwarfed by other large classes.  Still the network segments class 8 but misses eyeballs as background.

Comment: Isn't that expected since you have a heavily imbalanced class distribution? Segmenting and classifying are two different things, your model can be able to segment the input data successfully without being able to classify certain regions because of near inexistent examples in your dataset.

Comment: @Ivan in that case, how is class 8 being segmented pretty well? I am using focal loss that kinda penalizes more for missing rare/smaller labels. Do I have to just extend the number of samples in eyeballs region? Or are there gradient accumulation tricks so that the network only updates when all the classes are received or seen?